# Memory leak in SimplePie with a really large feed. How to fight this?

Tags: memory-leaks, simplepie

I'm trying to parse this RSS feed with SimplePie:

http://www.merdekapost.com/feeds/posts/default

And it creates a memory leak because the feed is huge. It's over 4 Mb and when SimplePie tries to parse XML it just fills all available RAM.

The thing is, I need to parse large feeds like this without giving up all my RAM to XML parser. I don't need all the items from this feed, only latest news, so maybe there's a way to only parse a part of XML? Can I edit (or configure) SimplePie to not fully parse large files like this?

I tried set_item_limit() but I guess it doesn't limit the amount of parsed XML.

I believe it's a common issue but I can't find an answer. Can you advice?

Answer (score 2):

If the memory leak is caused by the size of the xml page, you can retrieve the xml contents first with file_get_contents() or curl, and cut off unnecessary parts by your self. After that pass the modified data to SimplePie with [set_raw_data()](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/set_raw_data) to fetch feed items. An example is documented [here](http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/how_to_edit_part_of_the_feed_before_parsing_it?s%5B%5D=set&s%5B%5D=raw&s%5B%5D=data).